# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: waiting for evaluate.js load failed Firefox 23

Tags: rspec, selenium-webdriver

Today running my rspec tests, I get the following error whenever somewhere in a test theres a `page.execute_script' call.

```
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError:
   waiting for evaluate.js load failed
 # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130807-3105-fpynb7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8360:in `r'
 # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130807-3105-fpynb7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:392:in `fxdriver.Timer.prototype.runWhenTrue/g'
 # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130807-3105-fpynb7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:386:in `fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify'
```

There is a file evaluate.js in the /resources directory (instead of components) of the path above, as it is on other machines.

This happened after updating to Firefox 23 from 22. I haven't been able to rollback yet to confirm that returning to 22 indeed fixes the problem, but that's all that's changed I believe.

Has anyone else seen this problem?

Running Kubuntu 12.04, Capybara 1.1.4, selenium-webdriver gem 2.33.0

I tried updating Capybara to 2.whatever and selenium-webdriver to 2.34.0, no change.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I had the same problem on Mac OS X Lion with FF 23.

But the problem went away for me when I updated selenium-webdriver to 2.34.0

I added `gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 2.34.0"` into my Gemfile.

`bundle update selenium-webdriver`

`bundle install`

Cucumber works fine with selenium now.

Comment: Oooookay, I swear I did that before, but now it's working. Maybe I forgot to `install`, who knows. Anyways, fixed my problem so enjoy your accept, thanks!

Comment: Was seeing the same in a TestNG test. Simply removed the selenium-java-2.33.0.jar and replaced it with the selenium-java-2.34.0.jar.

Comment: When using Spork don't forget to stop and restart the server so it takes changes.

Comment: I get "LoadError: cannot load such file -- zip/zip"

Comment: You can fix the rubyzip issue with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555992/bundle-exec-rspec-spec-requests-static-pages-spec-rb-from-hartls-tutorial-isnt

Comment: OK, but then when I run cucumber, I get "cannot load such file -- zip/zip (LoadError)" and a stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

I have updated my gems to:

```
gem 'capybara',             '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'selenium-webdriver',   '~> 2.35.1'
```

This worked for me.

**Update:**

Capybara 2.1.0 has given me a problem with Phantomjs and finally I use 2.0.3 version.

Comment: This one works for me on Ubuntu 12.04LTS, when using Spork don't forget to stop and restart the server so it takes changes.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the below and it worked :

```
 gem install selenium-webdriver -v "2.35.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Selenium Webdriver recently and saw this same issue with some of my Python test scripts. After some digging I was able to determine that `execute_script` was hanging when it attempted to convert the JS return value into an object that could be natively evaluated (in Python for my scenario).

**Would hang:**

```
self.driver.execute_script('document.body.innerHTML="<form></form>";')
```

**Wouldn't hang:**

```
self.driver.execute_script('document.body.innerHTML="<form></form>"; return true;')
```

You can still return more complicated objects, I'm just careful to always explicitly have JS `return` the value I want or `true` if I just need the script to execute.

Hope this helps.

Some of the reading I did to figure this out:

- https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5979
- [Reading JavaScript variables using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994393/reading-javascript-variables-using-selenium-webdriver)