# bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb from Hartl's tutorial isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm following Michael Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial to test the sample app(3.2.1 Test-driven development), but I'm getting following error after typing `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`

```
/home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- zip/zip (LoadError)
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common.rb:9:in `require'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:29:in `require'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/rahul/Downloads/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rahul/Downloads/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /home/rahul/Downloads/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rahul/Downloads/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/rahul/Downloads/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rahul/Downloads/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/rahul/Downloads/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Here is the code from `spec/requests/static_pages_spec` file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App' " do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end

  end

end
```

`Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

`routes.rb`:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/help"
end
```

**OS**: Ubuntu 13.04

I've been searching for solution, but have not found one. Please keep in mind that I'm new to Ruby on Rails and web development.

Comment: I would guess you are missing a gem called "zip", that should have been installed along with selenium-web driver, but sometimes these things are not perfect. Try adding "gem 'zip'" to your test group, re-run bundle install

Comment: Since, there are no answers should I answer my own question to close the discussion?

Comment: You can ask Neil Slater to answer and then accept his

Comment: @NeilSlater :  What ScottJShea said! Can you answer the question? so that I can select best answer.

Comment: I have looked further into this, and think although my answer may have fixed the problem for installation, it may not be completely right (depending on compatibility between `zip` and `rubyzip` gems). I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message:

```
in `require': cannot load such file -- zip/zip (LoadError)
```

is referring to a missing gem called "rubyzip". It should have been installed by bundler along with selenium-web driver, but sometimes these things are not perfect. In this case, the latest version of the "rubyzip" gem has changed library structure, so 'zip/zip' does not exist. Bundler will by default install the latest version, which is why there is no error on install, but there will be an error when you try to run the project, because `selenium-webdriver` dependency lists are not aware of the difference.

Try adding `gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0'` to your test group, and re-run `bundle install`.

---

The problem appears to be caused by an update to the `rubyzip` gem, see https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip

The `selenium-webdriver` gem probably needs updating to reflect those changes - I have logged an issue: https://github.com/vertis/selenium-webdriver/issues/3

Comment: I came across this when upgrading a Rails 3 project to use `rspec-rails 2.14.0` and `capybara 2.1.0` and this answer solved the issue.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue recently and by just changing the version of the gem

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
```

to the last one :

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
```

it fixed it! Didn't have to install the rubyzip gem.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
```

to

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

in your Gemfile