# How do I click Enter using Splinter?

Tags: python, splinter

Here is my Splinter code -

```
b = Browser()
b.visit("http://boingboing.net")
b.fill("q", "OpenXC")
```

At this point, I would like to press "Enter" for the search to happen.

This is very similar to the example in the Splinter tutorial page. In this instance, there is really no button element present.

I see that this Search box is a Google Search Box with an id "cse-search-box". I do not know how to trigger search here.

Can you please help?

Metaphy's (thanks, btw) code below generates a traceback for me -

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/Users/muthu/Desktop/boing.py", line 5, in 
>       b.execute_script('document.getElementsByName("f")[0].submit()')
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/**init**.py", line 58, in execute_script
>       self.driver.execute_script(script)
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 397, in execute_script
>       {'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 158, in check_response 
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       WebDriverException: Message: u'waiting for evaluate.js load failed' ; Stacktrace: 
>       at r (file:///var/folders/5r/06jrtyyn2kd8ty05m71lm0hr0000gn/T/tmpBFCIVe/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8360)
>       at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.runWhenTrue/g (file:///var/folders/5r/06jrtyyn2kd8ty05m71lm0hr0000gn/T/tmpBFCIVe/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:392)
>       at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///var/folders/5r/06jrtyyn2kd8ty05m71lm0hr0000gn/T/tmpBFCIVe/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:386)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not access the http://boingboing.net site, so I take baidu.com for example:

```
from splinter.browser import Browser
b = Browser('firefox')
b.visit('http://www.baidu.com')
b.fill('wd', 'test')
b.execute_script('document.getElementsByName("f")[0].submit()')
```

New answer:

```
browser.fill('some_name', 'some_value\r')
```

Comment: The above code generates a traceback. See original post for details.

Comment: In principle, I can see what you are doing here. In my case, the form does not have a name attribute. So I ended up doing a `document.getELementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()`. It generated the same traceback as in the original post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114544/seleniumwebdrivererrorjavascripterror-waiting-for-evaluate-js-load-failed, you can search "evaluate.js load failed" for more similar questions.

Comment: That did it. `sudo pip install selenium --upgrade` updated Selenium from 2.33 to 2.35. And then my code worked. The above was on Mac OSX 10.8, FF23.