# Get CSS attribute of hidden element using Selenium

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, imageurl

I am trying to access `background-image:url('.....')` property of a container `div` and get the image url.

The problem is that the container div is initially hidden and image url is added dynamically and the container is made visible.

When i try to access the element using `photoContainer.getCssValue("background-image");` it returns me `none`.

The html code is :

```
<div id="photo_container" style="background-image: url("res/images/840x460/287/28702560.jpg");"></div>
```

The CSS for this div is :

```
background-image: url("res/images/840x460/287/28702560.jpg");
display: none;
```

However using the below code am able to get the url string:

```
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
       WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("photo_holding")));
       // Now div is visible so get the attribute
       WebElement photoContainer = driver.findElement(By.id("photo_holding"));
       String imgUrl = photoContainer.getCssValue("background-image");
       System.out.println(imgUrl);

   driver.quit();
```

The images are loaded as a slideshow using some time interval and my aim is to get the dynamically loaded image url

**EDIT :**

Below code is used to get the image url from the slide show :

```
 for(int i=0;i<=slideCount;i++){
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
       WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("photo_holding")));
       // Now div is visible so get the attribute
       WebElement photoContainer = driver.findElement(By.id("photo_holding"));
       String imgUrl = photoContainer.getCssValue("background-image");
       System.out.println(imgUrl);
       Thread.sleep(2000);
   }
```

The image container  "photo_holding" is added dynamically using the below code

```
$('<div id="photo_holding"></div>').insertAfter("#photo_container");$("#photo_holding").css("background-image","url("+slideshow_photos[o]+")");
 $("#photo_container").fadeOut(2000,function() {$(this).remove();$("#photo_holding").attr("id","photo_container");
```

Comment: Just a advice dont use `Thread.sleep`, `driver.get()` waits for page to load completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageURLs are stored in `slideshow_photos[]`, right? Then if we read it then we may able to get what we need.

According to [Reading JavaScript variables using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994393/reading-javascript-variables-using-selenium-webdriver) 3rd answer, if there anyway to get to know number of slides, then we may able to get them in a loop `String result = (String)js.executeScript("return slideshow_photos["+i+"]");`

Hope this may help you.

Comment: I want the url of dynamically loaded images. please see edited part of question.

Comment: Yes we know the number of slides. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try waiting til `div` gets visible

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("photo_container")));
// Now div is visible so get the attribute
WebElement photoContainer = driver.findElement(By.id("photo_container"));
String imgUrl = photoContainer.getCssValue("background-image");
```

Comment: Can you add the code which adds the attribute dynamically?

Comment: Well, it did gave result as `url("res/images/840x460/287/28702560.jpg");` . There was one child div which was hidden and actually containing the image url. But still, How would i get just the url `res/images/840x460/287/28702560.jpg` ?

Comment: Use [String Manipulation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html) and manipulate the retrieved string to what desire you need.

Comment: @VaibhavShukla: You can use `String.split()` and use second element from returned array

Comment: Actually its a slideshow which dynamically loads the images and i need to access the urls of each image. I know the slide count so i used up a loop but that doesn't seems to work as it is unable to find the photo_container. Please see the edit part of question.