# Python - How to print a javascript variable of a website in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to selenium, this is my first day of learning it so please go easy on me.

So I want to print `umidTokenFromHeader` a javascript variable of this website https://member.lazada.co.id/user/login. Here's my code so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://member.lazada.co.id/user/login")
# print (umidTokenFromHeader)
driver.close()
```

On the Console tab of Chrome Developer Tools, `umidTokenFromHeader` looks like this:

[image]

I found this question [Reading JavaScript variables using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994393/reading-javascript-variables-using-selenium-webdriver)
but I don't understand Java at all
How do I do this on selenium with python ?

Comment: In selenium you can evaluate JavaScript using driver.execute_script, try this to access your variable and see if that works

Comment: Can you provide the full code for that ?

Comment: sorry didnt notice your response, so you should just be able to get the value by doing this : ```driver.execute_script("return umidTokenFromHeader")``` and it should return the value for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JavaScript and `execute_script()` to return the value of `umidTokenFromHeader` variable. Then you can capture that value in `element` variable and finally print it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://member.lazada.co.id/user/login")
element = driver.execute_script("return umidTokenFromHeader")
print (element)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using python 3 so it should be `print (element)`