# is there a way to get js script from script tag with cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cheerio

So I'm trying to get data from my script tag HTML with cheerio

here is my scripttag.html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var playerInstance=jwplayer('smthing');
    playerInstance.setup(
        {
        title : '',
        tracks: [{
            file: '',
            kind: 'captions',
            'default': true
        }],
        sources: [{'file':'vidurl','type':'video/mp4'}],
        image: "imageurl",
        captions:
            {
            color:'#FFFF00',fontSize:17,backgroundOpacity:50
        },
    }
    );
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Im using Cheerio To load the html but... how do i really get the vidurl ?

here is my index.js:

```
const html = ("the scripttag.html")

    const cheerio = require("cheerio");


    let $ = cheerio.load(html)
const scripttag = $.html("head > script")

const title = ...
const srcfiles = ...
const image = ...
```

Now I got the script tag, but how do I get the

const title from playerintance.setup -> title

const srcfiles from playerinstance.setup -> sources -> file

const image from playerinstance.setup -> image

Comment: That's not possible with cheerio since it just scraps the site as plain text basically. Thus, the JS within the `<script>` is never executed. Unless there is a hardcoded value somewhere, you won't be able to get it. You could however try [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994393/reading-javascript-variables-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

You would use regex for that:

```
html.match(/\{'file':'(.*?)'/)[1]
```