# Java Selenium testing, can we get javaScript variables to assert

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, testing

I want to test a front end vanilla javascript using Selenium in java. I can easily open the page click on some stuff etc, but I couldn't figure out exactly what is the best practices to assert tests. Mainly, can we get the variables after clicking on some buttons, for example let's say:

```
function button(){
  variable = 2;
}
```

Let's say some button calls the function above, in selenium I can click on the function but is there a way to call the variable and do something like;

```
AssertEquals(2, driver.getVariableFromJavascriptAfterClick())
```

If not, how should I test something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need to do is

```java
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
int val = js.executeScript("return button();");
AssertEquals(2, val);
```

For more details see this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994393/reading-javascript-variables-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: I think button() would have to return a value for that to work, no?

Comment: You are right.. If so, is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: well, the example javascript function there is not really usable... I think the OP needs to provide a specific example of what they're trying to do.  Personally I'd focus on the DOM for Selenium tests.  To test the javascript portion of the page I think a "debug" version of the site should be created.  You could expose some things to the DOM/Selenium for convenience.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for attention and answers. I am trying to build an autonomous  testing for a web page @pcalkins .The real question is what is the best practices for opening the webpage ( either with mock objects or real ) and running it to see the output of some methods and making assertions. For example if I open the page with selenium and click on some stuff, can I get the related functions outputs at that run, no right? Executor seems it will run only that method, and global variables etc. links will be missing. Maybe I am thinking like testing a java code, can you guide me here.

Comment: I don't know much about "best practices"... but I'd use Selenium to test the front-end.  So make sure that whatever that javascript does is reflected in the DOM.  For testing Javascript I would go another route.  Maybe build asserts into the scripts.  For convenience, you might expose some of the javascript return objects to the DOM so Selenium can check them.